# How to Append radio buttons to dynamic html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an ajax call that returns a sql query result and parses it into an html table. See below:

```
function CreateTableFromJSON() {
  var email = "<?php echo $user_email; ?>";
  console.log(email);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'api.php',
    data:{ 
      //format:'json'
      //data:$.param({
        'userEmail': email 
    },
    dataType: 'json',   
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      console.log("success");

      // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
      var col = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (var key in data[i]) {
          if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
            col.push(key);
          }
        }
      } 

      // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
      var table = document.getElementById('excel_tablebody2');           
      var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.

      //for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
      //  var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
      //  th.innerHTML = col[i];
      //  tr.appendChild(th);
      //}

      // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS data.
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
          var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
          tabCell.innerHTML = data[i][col[j]];
        }
      }

      // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
      var divContainer = document.getElementById("excel_table2");            
      divContainer.appendChild(table);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
      console.log("CreateTableFromJSON did not work.....");
    }
  });    
};
```

I'd like to append radio buttons to the table. Specifically how can I do this for dynamic tables (undefined number of rows and or columns)?

In addition the radio button would need to relate to a specific tr as it will need to be used to send data back for that tr

The goal is to return the table based on some criteria (user email).
The table will contain data that needs to be verified using the radio buttons. Yes/No button and then sent back.

**Edit**

I'll add I'm unsure how to approach my overall goal.
Is it best to allow the user to update the each row by using the radio button and once done submit it all back to the server. OR have each radio button fire an individual 'update' back to the server as you progress. Live update vs bulk update?

Comment: same way you create rows and cells for undefined number of rows. Just increment name value for each row

Comment: @charlietfl Right, by iterating through and appending each row with a another td containing the radio buttons. I guess I don't understand how the ids for the new radio buttons td should be tied back to that row.

Comment: You only need the event handlers to be tied to the row...by using traverse methods. Using jQuery for example `$('#excel_tablebody2').on('change', ':radio', function(){ var $row = $(this).closest('tr');})`

Comment: Thank you, and with that I assume it's best to use a live update? Rather than allowing the user to update the radio buttons then submitting that back as a bulk change? That maybe be a subjective question.

Comment: Really depends on the UI and whether you want changes to be transparent to user or they need to do a "save all"